# Would this question have been better to ask in Astronomy? Could it be split it into two? Something else?

Tags: discussion

I've asked the question [What might the first deep space telescope using the Sun or Jupiter as a gravitational lens be like?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31815/12102) in Space Exploration SE. I chose that site because it involves propulsion and coordination of possibly an array of space telescopes. I left a message in The Observatory (chat) as well as a "heads-up" to whomever actually checks there.

But the question also about telescope instrumentation, data analysis, and image reconstruction from a gravitational lens which do not work the same as "normal" lenses (deflection varies as $r^{-1}$ rather than $r$).

I wonder, should I split this into two, and ask the imaging part here? Or perhaps just ask an open-ed up, basic question about image reconstruction from gravitational lenses here instead? (do algorithms exist, how hard would it be, what would need to be measured, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question there seems well-received. I would leave it as is, and if you would like, ask a new question here tailored to this community to gather further detail.

Comment: Almost there... thanks!